# SQL Server Pivoting a Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am using SQL Server and am trying to list Names by Occupation, could someone help me understand why below wouldn't work? Here is the original question source: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/occupations/problem?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen&h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

```
select *
from (select Name, Occupation from OCCUPATIONS)
PIVOT(Name for Occupation in ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor])) as pivot_table;
```

Comment: Don't link to external sites, include a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in the body of your question. Links to external resources tend to break and nuke any value for future visitors to the question.

Comment: you think, someone going to click on the link saying "hacker"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `row_number()` to rank names for each occupation, and then conditional aggregation to pivot the dataset:

```
select
    max(case when occupation = 'Doctor' then name end) doctor,
    max(case when occupation = 'Professor' then name end) professor,
    max(case when occupation = 'Singer' then name end) singer,
    max(case when occupation = 'Actor' then name end) actor
from (
    select o.*, row_number() over(partition by occupation order by name) rn
    from occupations o
) t
group by rn
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=860bf60c5aa4a06c3bc79775ef40fb5d)**

Sample data:

```
name      | occupation
:-------- | :---------
Samantha  | Doctor    
Julia     | Actor     
Maria     | Actor     
Meera     | Singer    
Ashely    | Professor 
Ketty     | Professor 
Christeen | Professor 
Jane      | Actor     
Jenny     | Doctor    
Priya     | Singer
```

Results:

```
doctor   | professor | singer | actor
:------- | :-------- | :----- | :----
Jenny    | Ashely    | Meera  | Jane 
Samantha | Christeen | Priya  | Julia
null     | Ketty     | null   | Maria
```

Comment: Thank you for explanation, it worked but I'm having trouble understanding the following points: what do you use **max** for? , what does o.* stand for?

Comment: @BasakUlcay: `o` is an alias for `occupation`, so `à.*` stands for all columns in `occupation`. We need `max()` to aggregate data so we only get one record per row number (`rn` which is computed in the inner query).

Answer (score 0):

You should write your column in select and use aggregate function like `count` on your query.

```
select 'count' as name_count, 
    [Doctor],
    [Professor],
    [Singer],
    [Actor] 
from (select Name, Occupation from OCCUPATIONS) as s_t
PIVOT(Count(Name) for Occupation in ([Doctor],[Professor],[Singer],[Actor])) as pivot_table;
```

Comment: It is bringing the number of names per occupation, I'm trying to list the names by occupation.